ImportError: cannot import name 'LSTM' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'
I am trying to build a ML model with LSTM. I want to import the 'LSTM' layer. However, my code does not lead to correct results. The error forces me to use 'LSTMV1' instead. But, I want to use 'LSTM'.
I tried this, and this did not work.
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

This is the error I am getting,
ImportError: cannot import name 'LSTM' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'

You should not import from tensorflow.python, just use tensorflow.keras.layers.LSTM.

That does not even work.

This is because you are trying to import the LSTM layer from the tensorflow.python module which doesn't work for keras version 3.
Here’s how you can import it correctly:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

